# Issues with setTimeout() inside jQuery .each

Tags: jquery, settimeout, each

The following code will not work properly. I've tried different variations & searching everywhere but no luck.

```
i = 1;
var timer = new Array();
jQuery('a').each(function($) {
    i++;
    timer[i] = setTimeout(jQuery(this).remove(), i * 5000)
})
```

Comment: *The following code will not work properly.* What do you want it to do? I assume your problem is that you are calling `jQuery(this).remove()` immediately.

Comment: Also note that the first argument passed to `each` is actually the index of the DOM element in the set of selected elements. That means you don't have to maintain a separate counter. [More information in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap remove element with a function

```
i = 1;
var timer = new Array();
jQuery('a').each(function($) {
    i++;
    var thiz = jQuery(this);
    timer[i] = setTimeout(function() { thiz.remove(); }, i * 5000);
})
```

Answer (score 4):

The first parameter to `setTimeout` (or `setInterval`) needs to be a reference to a function (or a string, but you don't want to use the string syntax).

Instead of passing a function as a parameter you are calling a function and passing its result. If you remove the parentheses you'll pass a reference to the function:

```
timer[i] = setTimeout(jQuery(this).remove, i * 5000)
```

But then you'll start having trouble with `this` being the wrong thing at the time the function actually runs. Try something like this:

```
var i = 1,
    timer = [];
jQuery('a').each(function($) {
    i++;
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    timer[i] = setTimeout(function() {$this.remove();}, i * 5000)
})
```

This takes advantage of the way closures work in that the anonymous function passed to `setTimeout` will have access to the `$this` variable at the time it is run even though the function in which `$this` is declared will have finished executing by then.

Note that it is better to declare arrays with `[]` than `new Array()`.

Note also that you initialise `i` to 1, then increment it before using it such that the first element that you add to your array will be `timer[2]`. You probably should initialise it to 0 and then increment it after setting each timer.

Answer (score 3):

Felix has already hinted at the issue in the comments, but I will expand.

```
timer[i] = setTimeout(jQuery(this).remove(), i * 5000)
```

Your issue lies in the fact that you are invoking `jQuery(this).remove()` and passing the return value of this to your `setTimeout`.  The assumption is that you are intending for this to run when the timeout expires.  If that is the case, you need to wrap this in a function, so that function will be passed to `setTimeout` and executed when the timer expires.

```
var $el = jQuery(this);

timer[i] = setTimeout(function(){
    $el.remove()
}, i * 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<a href="#">a</a>
<a href="#">a</a>
<a href="#">a</a>
<a href="#">a</a>
<a href="#">a</a>
<a href="#">a</a>
<script>
i = 1;
var timer = new Array();
    jQuery('a').each(function($) {
    i++;
    timer[i] = setTimeout(jQuery.proxy(function(){jQuery(this).remove();},this), i * 500);
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

`setTimeout` accepts javascript statements not the return value of `jQuery(this).remove()` :P
See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

You can just `function(){stuff}` but not sure if `jQuery(this)` will be processed when you want it to.