# settimeout not working in block ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, blockui, jquery-blockui

I am using block ui for blocking the div on button click. But after blocking i want the div should be unblocked after some delay. But in my case the div is blocking permanently. Here is my code:

```
<script src="jQuery 1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="blockui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Button1').click(function () {
                $('div#blockit').block({

                    message: '<h6>Processing</h6>',
                    css: { border: '3px solid #a00' }


                });
                setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 
            });

        });

    </script>



    <div>
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
    </div>

    <div id="blockit" style="width: 200px; height=200px;">

    </div>
```

I am unable to figure out why that settimeout is not working. Please give me the solution. Thanx in advance.

Comment: this may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797421/issues-with-settimeout-inside-jquery-each

Answer (score 0):

try it as

```
setTimeout(function(){ $.unblockUI },2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#Button1').click(function () {
            $('div#blockit').block({

                message: '<h6>Processing</h6>',
                css: { border: '3px solid #a00' },
                timeout:2000

            });
            //setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're getting a JavaScript error because unblockui may use `this` and calling it the way you do changes `this` into window.

If you press F12 in a browser do you see a script error in the console?

```
            setTimeout(function(){
              $.unblockUI
            }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
$('div#blockit').unblock()
```

This is the difference

```
$('id').block() -> $('id').unblock()

$.blockUI() -> $.unblockUI()
```

Comment: Please remember to use the code blocks when posting code snippets.